# How to send notifications to all users (or topic subscribers) on a in app button click?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, I have an activity with some textViews and a button. I need the button to send the notifications to all users. Something like the Instagram notification: this user has posted a new picture or a story. I am not finding any way to send notifications than through a firebase console. Anything would be helpful.

I have added the FCM to my app but don't know how to associate the button with sending the notification to the users.

If this is possible could someone send a link to a website or a tutorial because I honestly can't find the answer. I really don't want to waste someone's time and just want to know if this is possible and how. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the Firebase documentation

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send

The devices to which you want to send Messages have to Register to a Topic or you have to know their firebasetoken to send Messages directly to them.

Messages are beeing sent from a Server by addressing the FCM Server to send Messages in a specified Format.